# C#: When adding an Item to a List, the previous List Items get overwritten with the Item as well. Why?

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, instantiation, insertion-sort

I have implemented the insertion sort algorithm in C#. The method returns a `List<List<string>>` which records all of the steps and changes that the `List` experienced, variables that were selected etc.

Here is the method:

```
public List<List<int>> SortStepByStep(List<int> set)
{
    List<List<int>> steps = new List<List<int>>();
    steps.Add(set); 

    for (int c1 = 1; c1 < set.Count; c1++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(steps[0][0].ToString());

        int item = set[c1];

        set.Add(item);
        steps.Add(set);
        set.RemoveAt(set.Count - 1);
        // ^^^^ This is just to visually display what number is being selected.

        set.RemoveAt(c1);

        steps.Add(set); 

        bool inserted = false;
        for (int c2 = 0; c2 < c1; c2++)
        {
            if ((set[c2] > item || c2 == c1 - 1) && !inserted)
            {
                set.Insert((set[c2] <= item && (c2 == c1 - 1) ? c2 + 1 : c2), item);
                steps.Add(set); 
                inserted = true; 
                break;
                // Added the break in anyway because sometimes the inserted boolean failed to work.
            }
        }
    }
    return steps;
}
```

What the method actually returns is just the final sorted list at every index of 'steps'. I've followed it through with writing the 'steps' to the console and can see it gradually changing, but do not understand why.

Other answers mention instantiating within the for loop, but I don't think that's applicable here.

What may be the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you are adding one and the same list object **reference** to your `steps` (it does not make a copy for you). Replace **all** `steps.Add(set);` with `steps.Add(set.ToList());`

Comment: Thank-you so much, I didn't understand that that was how it worked. Thanks for saving me a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

Your **steps** list holding *references* to the same collection. Because of that, once you modify **set**, each element of the **steps** will show you updated value (they are pointing to the same object).

Try change `steps.Add(set);` to `steps.Add(set.ToList())` or `steps.Add(new List<int>(set))`, that should create new list instead of referencing old one.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, I need to read into the theory/msdn pages a bit more carefully!